# Finding the norm of the Taylor approximation of a multivariate function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$. My goal is to bound the first order Taylor approximation of $f$. Given $x,x'\in\mathbb{R}^n$ I have that
\begin{equation}
f(x)-f(x')\approx (x-x')^TDf(x')+(x-x')^THf(x')(x-x')+\mathcal{O}\left(\left\Vert x-x' \right\Vert^3\right),
\end{equation}
where $Df(x')$ and $Hf(x')$ define the Jacobian and Hessian w.r.t $x'$, respectively. Taking the 2-norm of each side we get

\begin{align}
\left\Vert f(x)-f(x')-(x-x')^TDf(x')\right\Vert_2&\leq \left\Vert(x-x')^THf(x')(x-x')\right\Vert_2\\
&\leq\left\Vert H f(x')\right \Vert_2\left\Vert x-x'\right \Vert^2_2 \quad (\text{operator norm}).\\
&\leq C \left\Vert x-x'\right \Vert^2_2\\
\end{align}

My goal is to bound (and find $C$) such that $\left\Vert Hf(x') \right \Vert_2\leq C$. The confusion I have is that as $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, the Jacobian and Hessian are both tensors. Is the correct approach to split $f=(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n)$ and take $n$ separate Taylor approximations of $f_j:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^m$ for $j=1:n$ and then we would have $\left\Vert Hf(x') \right \Vert_2^2=\sum_{j=1}^n\left\Vert Hf_j(x') \right\Vert_2^2$ where $Hf_j(x')$ is the individual Hessian of $f_j$ at the point $x'$ ?

Or am I missing something blindingly obvious here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I changed $f:\mathbb R^n\mapsto\mathbb R^m$ to $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ because the kind of arrow that was there before is intended for such things as distingushing the function $x\mapsto(x+2y)^3$ from the function $y\mapsto(x+2y)^3. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use this form of taylor ormula $f(x+h)=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{1\le i_1 ... i_k \le n}\frac{\partial^k f}{\partial x_{i_1}...\partial x_{i_k}}(x)h_{i_1}...h_{i_k} + o(\|h\|^N)$. Note than $\frac{\partial^k f}{\partial x_{i_1}...\partial x_{i_k}}(x)\in \mathbb R^m$. So for $\sum_{i,j=1}^n \frac{\partial^k f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(x) h_i h_j$, its norm $\le \max_{i,j}\|\frac{\partial^k f}{\partial x_i\partial  x_j}(x)\|_{2,\mathbb R^m} (\max_{1...n}|h_i|)^2$, and $\max_{1...n}|h_i|\le C(n) \|h\|_{2,\mathbb R^n}$.